# How to vectorize a function that already takes a vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to plot a contour of the [Rastrigin function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrigin_function) in R.

To do so, I'm creating a tibble with three columns, `x`, `y`, and `value`. However, since the function signature is `TF_rastrigin(x)` where `x` is an input vector, I'm having problems calculating the values correctly. I want a tibble that looks like this:

```
x        y       value
-5.12    5.12    57.84943
-5.11    5.11    56.81394
...
```

In order to pass it to ggplot. My current code looks like this:

```
install.packages("TestFunctions")
require(TestFunctions)
dim <- 100
mw <- tibble(x = seq(0, pi, length.out = dim), y = seq(0, pi, length.out = dim), value = TF_rastrigin(c(x,y)))
ggplot(mw, aes(x = x, y = y ,z = value)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_contour()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way?

Comment: Did you write your own Rastrigin function or is this from a package? If it is from a package can you mention it or tag it? Are you just running it with n = 2?

Comment: @CalumYou: My apologies. I've added both installation and require now. And yes, N = 2 is all I need for the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want `x` and `y` to be defined differently: currently `x` and `y` columns coincide, while you need all possible combinations of their values. For that we may use `expand.grid`. As for the Rastrigin function, we may simply use `apply` as to go row by row and get a function value at each point separately:

```
dim <- 100
mw <- expand.grid(x = seq(0, pi, length.out = dim),
                  y = seq(0, pi, length.out = dim))
mw$value <- apply(mw, 1, TF_rastrigin)
ggplot(mw, aes(x = x, y = y ,z = value)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) + geom_contour()
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. Next step is for me to understand what you just did, but it's 1:00 am :)

Comment: @TroelsLarsen, as to understand `expand.grid`, just take a look at how `mw` looks like now and before, and what the plot would look like without `expand.grid`. Then `apply` goes row by row (1 stands for that dimension) and to each row (which is a vector (x,y)) applies `TF_rastrigin`.

Comment: Ah, actually simple enough. I had already tried with outer and a matrix and failed horribly. This solution is easy enough to understand, and very clear. Once again, thanks!